# Calculate multiple distances between two GPS coordinates and classify results in two columns

Tags: r, gps, geosphere

I'm new to R so I hope this question will be interesting enough. I'm working with GPS location data for which I have both latitude and longitude positions and an associated time and date.

Here's a sample of the data:

```
> dataraw<-fread("41361_GPS_data_raw.csv", select = c("Date & Time [Local]","Latitude","Longitude"))
> head(dataraw)
   Date & Time [Local]  Latitude Longitude
1:      6/18/2018 3:01 -2.434901  34.85359
2:      6/18/2018 3:06 -2.434598  34.85387
3:      6/18/2018 3:08 -2.434726  34.85382
4:      6/18/2018 3:12 -2.434816  34.85371
5:      6/18/2018 3:16 -2.434613  34.85372
6:      6/18/2018 3:20 -2.434511  34.85376
```

I would like to create a dataframe with two columns "Day" and "Night" which partition the hours of the day as "Day" [6:00 to 18:00] and "Night" [18:00 to 6:00].

- The column "Day" will have the total distance travelled (in meters) based on GPS positions from [6:00 to 18:00]
- The column "Night" will have the total distance travelled (in meters) based on GPS positions from [18:00 to 6:00]

I'm using the package `geosphere` to calculate distances between two locations but I'm unsure wether there's a more efficient function to compute my analysis. Note that GPS locations where taken for several months so this is a big dataset.

If the data needs to be transformed prior to that, please let me know as well. Any input is appreciated.

P.S. Large sample of the data

```
> dput(dataraw)
structure(list(`Date & Time [Local]` = c("18/06/2018 03:01", 
"18/06/2018 03:06", "18/06/2018 03:08", "18/06/2018 03:12", "18/06/2018 03:16", 
"18/06/2018 03:20", "18/06/2018 03:24", "18/06/2018 03:28", "18/06/2018 03:33", 
"18/06/2018 03:36", "18/06/2018 03:40", "18/06/2018 03:45", "18/06/2018 03:48", 
"18/06/2018 03:52", "18/06/2018 03:56", "18/06/2018 04:00", "18/06/2018 04:04", 
"18/06/2018 04:08", "18/06/2018 04:12", "18/06/2018 04:16", "18/06/2018 04:20", 
"18/06/2018 04:24", "18/06/2018 04:28", "18/06/2018 04:32", "18/06/2018 04:36", 
"18/06/2018 04:40", "18/06/2018 04:44", "18/06/2018 04:48", "18/06/2018 04:52", 
"18/06/2018 04:56", "18/06/2018 05:00", "18/06/2018 05:04", "18/06/2018 05:08", 
"18/06/2018 05:12", "18/06/2018 05:16", "18/06/2018 05:20", "18/06/2018 05:24", 
"18/06/2018 05:28", "18/06/2018 05:32", "18/06/2018 05:36", "18/06/2018 05:40", 
"18/06/2018 05:44", "18/06/2018 05:48", "18/06/2018 05:52", "18/06/2018 05:56", 
"18/06/2018 06:00", "18/06/2018 06:05", "18/06/2018 06:08", "18/06/2018 06:12", 
"18/06/2018 06:16", "18/06/2018 06:20", "18/06/2018 06:24", "18/06/2018 06:28", 
"18/06/2018 06:32", "18/06/2018 06:36", "18/06/2018 06:40", "18/06/2018 06:44", 
"18/06/2018 06:48", "18/06/2018 06:52", "18/06/2018 06:57", "18/06/2018 07:01", 
"18/06/2018 07:04", "18/06/2018 07:08", "18/06/2018 07:12", "18/06/2018 07:17", 
"18/06/2018 07:20", "18/06/2018 07:24", "18/06/2018 07:28", "18/06/2018 07:32", 
"18/06/2018 07:36", "18/06/2018 07:40", "18/06/2018 07:44", "18/06/2018 07:48", 
"18/06/2018 07:52", "18/06/2018 07:56", "18/06/2018 08:00", "18/06/2018 08:04", 
"18/06/2018 08:08", "18/06/2018 08:12", "18/06/2018 08:16", "18/06/2018 08:20", 
"18/06/2018 08:24", "18/06/2018 08:28", "18/06/2018 08:32", "18/06/2018 08:36", 
"18/06/2018 08:40", "18/06/2018 08:44", "18/06/2018 08:48", "18/06/2018 08:52", 
"18/06/2018 08:56", "18/06/2018 09:00", "18/06/2018 09:04", "18/06/2018 09:08", 
"18/06/2018 09:12", "18/06/2018 09:16", "18/06/2018 09:20", "18/06/2018 09:24", 
"18/06/2018 09:28", "18/06/2018 09:32", "18/06/2018 09:37", "18/06/2018 09:40", 
"18/06/2018 09:44", "18/06/2018 09:48", "18/06/2018 09:52", "18/06/2018 09:56", 
"18/06/2018 10:00", "18/06/2018 10:05", "18/06/2018 10:08", "18/06/2018 10:12", 
"18/06/2018 10:17", "18/06/2018 10:20", "18/06/2018 10:25", "18/06/2018 10:29", 
"18/06/2018 10:32", "18/06/2018 10:36", "18/06/2018 10:40", "18/06/2018 10:44", 
"18/06/2018 10:48", "18/06/2018 10:52", "18/06/2018 10:56", "18/06/2018 11:01", 
"18/06/2018 11:04", "18/06/2018 11:09", "18/06/2018 11:12", "18/06/2018 11:17", 
"18/06/2018 11:22", "18/06/2018 11:25", "18/06/2018 11:30", "18/06/2018 11:33", 
"18/06/2018 11:36", "18/06/2018 11:41", "18/06/2018 11:46", "18/06/2018 11:49", 
"18/06/2018 11:53", "18/06/2018 11:56", "18/06/2018 12:01", "18/06/2018 12:05", 
"18/06/2018 12:09", "18/06/2018 12:13", "18/06/2018 12:17", "18/06/2018 12:22", 
"18/06/2018 12:27", "18/06/2018 12:29", "18/06/2018 12:33", "18/06/2018 12:38", 
"18/06/2018 12:41", "18/06/2018 12:44", "18/06/2018 12:48", "18/06/2018 12:52", 
"18/06/2018 12:56", "18/06/2018 13:00", "18/06/2018 13:04", "18/06/2018 13:08", 
"18/06/2018 13:12", "18/06/2018 13:16", "18/06/2018 13:20", "18/06/2018 13:24", 
"18/06/2018 13:29", "18/06/2018 13:34", "18/06/2018 13:37", "18/06/2018 13:40", 
"18/06/2018 13:44", "18/06/2018 13:48", "18/06/2018 13:52", "18/06/2018 13:56", 
"18/06/2018 14:00", "18/06/2018 14:04", "18/06/2018 14:08", "18/06/2018 14:12", 
"18/06/2018 14:16", "18/06/2018 14:20", "18/06/2018 14:24", "18/06/2018 14:29", 
"18/06/2018 14:32", "18/06/2018 14:36", "18/06/2018 14:40", "18/06/2018 14:44", 
"18/06/2018 14:48", "18/06/2018 14:52", "18/06/2018 14:56", "18/06/2018 15:01", 
"18/06/2018 15:04", "18/06/2018 15:08", "18/06/2018 15:12", "18/06/2018 15:16", 
"18/06/2018 15:21", "18/06/2018 15:24", "18/06/2018 15:28", "18/06/2018 15:32", 
"18/06/2018 15:36", "18/06/2018 15:40", "18/06/2018 15:44", "18/06/2018 15:48", 
"18/06/2018 15:52", "18/06/2018 15:56", "18/06/2018 16:00", "18/06/2018 16:04", 
"18/06/2018 16:08", "18/06/2018 16:12", "18/06/2018 16:16", "18/06/2018 16:20", 
"18/06/2018 16:24", "18/06/2018 16:28", "18/06/2018 16:32", "18/06/2018 16:36", 
"18/06/2018 16:40", "18/06/2018 16:44", "18/06/2018 16:48", "18/06/2018 16:52", 
"18/06/2018 16:56", "18/06/2018 17:00", "18/06/2018 17:04", "18/06/2018 17:08", 
"18/06/2018 17:12", "18/06/2018 17:16", "18/06/2018 17:20", "18/06/2018 17:24", 
"18/06/2018 17:28", "18/06/2018 17:32", "18/06/2018 17:36", "18/06/2018 17:40", 
"18/06/2018 17:44", "18/06/2018 17:48", "18/06/2018 17:52", "18/06/2018 17:56", 
"18/06/2018 18:00", "18/06/2018 18:04", "18/06/2018 18:08", "18/06/2018 18:12", 
"18/06/2018 18:16", "18/06/2018 18:20", "18/06/2018 18:24", "18/06/2018 18:28", 
"18/06/2018 18:32", "18/06/2018 18:36", "18/06/2018 18:40", "18/06/2018 18:44", 
"18/06/2018 18:48", "18/06/2018 18:52", "18/06/2018 18:56", "18/06/2018 19:00", 
"18/06/2018 19:04", "18/06/2018 19:08", "18/06/2018 19:12", "18/06/2018 19:16", 
"18/06/2018 19:20", "18/06/2018 19:24", "18/06/2018 19:28", "18/06/2018 19:32", 
"18/06/2018 19:36", "18/06/2018 19:40", "18/06/2018 19:44", "18/06/2018 19:48", 
"18/06/2018 19:52", "18/06/2018 19:56", "18/06/2018 20:00", "18/06/2018 20:04", 
"18/06/2018 20:08", "18/06/2018 20:12", "18/06/2018 20:16", "18/06/2018 20:20", 
"18/06/2018 20:24", "18/06/2018 20:28", "18/06/2018 20:32", "18/06/2018 20:36", 
"18/06/2018 20:40", "18/06/2018 20:44", "18/06/2018 20:48", "18/06/2018 20:52", 
"18/06/2018 20:56", "18/06/2018 21:00", "18/06/2018 21:04", "18/06/2018 21:08", 
"18/06/2018 21:12", "18/06/2018 21:16", "18/06/2018 21:20", "18/06/2018 21:24", 
"18/06/2018 21:28", "18/06/2018 21:32", "18/06/2018 21:36", "18/06/2018 21:40", 
"18/06/2018 21:44", "18/06/2018 21:48", "18/06/2018 21:52", "18/06/2018 21:56", 
"18/06/2018 22:00", "18/06/2018 22:04", "18/06/2018 22:08", "18/06/2018 22:12", 
"18/06/2018 22:16", "18/06/2018 22:20", "18/06/2018 22:24", "18/06/2018 22:28", 
"18/06/2018 22:32", "18/06/2018 22:36", "18/06/2018 22:40", "18/06/2018 22:44", 
"18/06/2018 22:48", "18/06/2018 22:52", "18/06/2018 22:56", "18/06/2018 23:00", 
"18/06/2018 23:04", "18/06/2018 23:08", "18/06/2018 23:12", "18/06/2018 23:16", 
"18/06/2018 23:20", "18/06/2018 23:24", "18/06/2018 23:28", "18/06/2018 23:32", 
"18/06/2018 23:36", "18/06/2018 23:40", "18/06/2018 23:44", "18/06/2018 23:48", 
"18/06/2018 23:52", "18/06/2018 23:56", "19/06/2018 00:00", "19/06/2018 00:04", 
"19/06/2018 00:08", "19/06/2018 00:12", "19/06/2018 00:16", "19/06/2018 00:20", 
"19/06/2018 00:24", "19/06/2018 00:28", "19/06/2018 00:32", "19/06/2018 00:36", 
"19/06/2018 00:40", "19/06/2018 00:44", "19/06/2018 00:48", "19/06/2018 00:52", 
"19/06/2018 00:56", "19/06/2018 01:00", "19/06/2018 01:04", "19/06/2018 01:08", 
"19/06/2018 01:12", "19/06/2018 01:16", "19/06/2018 01:20", "19/06/2018 01:24", 
"19/06/2018 01:28", "19/06/2018 01:32", "19/06/2018 01:36", "19/06/2018 01:40"
), Latitude = c(-2.4349008, -2.4345981, -2.4347258, -2.4348164, 
-2.4346131, -2.4345111, -2.4345033, -2.4347186, -2.4347181, -2.4348167, 
-2.4346744, -2.434745, -2.4346639, -2.4346708, -2.4346603, -2.4346686, 
-2.4346839, -2.4346917, -2.4346292, -2.4346547, -2.4347036, -2.4346725, 
-2.4346589, -2.4346833, -2.434695, -2.4346175, -2.4345903, -2.4346786, 
-2.4346525, -2.434615, -2.4346125, -2.4345792, -2.4345994, -2.4346414, 
-2.4346417, -2.4346753, -2.4346939, -2.4346256, -2.4346519, -2.4346192, 
-2.4346089, -2.4346731, -2.4347681, -2.4347239, -2.4346814, -2.4347231, 
-2.4346, -2.4346792, -2.4346072, -2.4346389, -2.4346383, -2.434605, 
-2.4347006, -2.4347186, -2.4346558, -2.4346703, -2.4346744, -2.4346983, 
-2.4348144, -2.4344161, -2.43485, -2.4348183, -2.4346917, -2.4346072, 
-2.43465, -2.4345392, -2.4346864, -2.4346872, -2.4346269, -2.4345764, 
-2.4346433, -2.4346817, -2.4346928, -2.4346631, -2.4346525, -2.4348539, 
-2.4346383, -2.4345847, -2.4345206, -2.4347272, -2.4346569, -2.4345236, 
-2.4346842, -2.4347886, -2.4346625, -2.4346364, -2.4346333, -2.4345917, 
-2.4346356, -2.4346767, -2.4346158, -2.4346472, -2.4346192, -2.4347022, 
-2.4346811, -2.4346297, -2.4346111, -2.4346622, -2.4346675, NA, 
-2.4346772, -2.4346939, -2.4346461, -2.4346019, -2.4346139, -2.4348478, 
-2.4347394, -2.4346625, -2.4346439, -2.4346794, -2.4347111, -2.434585, 
-2.4347006, -2.4347433, -2.4346411, -2.4347028, -2.4346817, -2.4347439, 
-2.4346769, -2.4346361, -2.4346717, -2.4346219, -2.4347819, -2.4347103, 
-2.4347506, -2.4346897, -2.4346925, -2.4346978, -2.4346964, -2.4347219, 
-2.4347267, -2.4345564, -2.4346508, -2.4346486, -2.4346811, -2.4350631, 
-2.4348117, -2.4347906, -2.4347039, -2.4349119, -2.4347797, NA, 
-2.4346444, NA, -2.4346842, -2.4346911, -2.4347128, -2.4347997, 
-2.4347008, -2.4347275, -2.4347192, -2.434735, -2.4345725, -2.4347472, 
-2.4346994, -2.4346981, -2.4346889, -2.4345267, -2.4347344, -2.4346525, 
-2.4345986, -2.4346194, -2.43469, -2.434695, -2.4346586, -2.4346967, 
-2.4346347, -2.4346678, -2.4346183, -2.4346778, -2.4346742, -2.4346319, 
-2.4346044, -2.4347036, -2.4347056, -2.4345906, -2.4345814, -2.4347161, 
-2.4347058, -2.4349583, -2.4344272, -2.4402072, -2.4306572, -2.4384197, 
-2.4377283, -2.4367728, -2.4369347, -2.4367983, -2.4365889, -2.4386911, 
-2.4384722, -2.4377939, -2.4377661, -2.4374156, -2.4374167, -2.4381381, 
-2.4382022, -2.4383194, -2.4382017, -2.4379392, -2.4379406, -2.4374514, 
-2.43689, -2.4369081, -2.4367461, -2.4365292, -2.4364558, -2.4364569, 
-2.4364564, -2.4364558, -2.4364467, -2.4367092, -2.4366642, -2.4366719, 
-2.4366094, -2.4366461, -2.4366547, -2.4366547, -2.4367356, -2.4366725, 
-2.4366728, -2.4367275, -2.4368083, -2.4369419, -2.436935, -2.4369522, 
-2.4370344, -2.4371542, -2.4370969, -2.4370978, -2.4370972, -2.4370983, 
-2.4370972, -2.4370894, -2.4370972, -2.4373953, -2.4373425, -2.4373597, 
-2.4373503, -2.4373517, -2.4373506, -2.4373431, -2.4373428, -2.4373431, 
-2.4373442, -2.4373333, -2.4373439, -2.4373422, -2.4373614, -2.4373433, 
-2.4373331, -2.4373436, -2.4373603, -2.4373436, -2.4372525, -2.4371892, 
-2.4371886, -2.4372075, -2.4372344, -2.4372058, -2.4372344, -2.4372439, 
-2.4372525, -2.4372342, -2.4372433, -2.4372525, -2.4372519, -2.4372439, 
-2.4372522, -2.4372519, -2.4372356, -2.4372356, -2.4372447, -2.4372453, 
-2.4372536, -2.4372531, -2.4372447, -2.4372467, -2.437235, -2.4372431, 
-2.4372508, -2.4372344, -2.4372344, -2.4372428, -2.4372519, -2.4373531, 
-2.4373708, -2.4373522, -2.4373878, -2.4373611, -2.4373336, -2.4373125, 
-2.4373522, -2.4373522, -2.4373433, -2.4373339, -2.4373525, -2.4373525, 
-2.4373433, -2.4373442, -2.4373519, -2.4373417, -2.4373597, -2.4373533, 
-2.4373528, -2.4373517, -2.4373508, -2.4373539, -2.4373519, -2.4373444, 
-2.4373531, -2.4373614, -2.4373619, -2.4373531, -2.4373458, -2.4373525, 
-2.4373606, -2.4373453, -2.4373531, -2.4369633, -2.4366472, -2.4366381, 
-2.4366467, -2.4363933, -2.4363844, -2.4363481, -2.4363572, -2.4363397, 
-2.4362944, -2.4363042, -2.4362858, -2.4363575, -2.4365206, -2.4365833, 
-2.4365389, -2.4365572, -2.4364672, -2.4365031, -2.4365206, -2.4365294, 
-2.4365119), Longitude = c(34.8535933, 34.8538736, 34.8538225, 
34.8537108, 34.853725, 34.8537628, 34.8539311, 34.8538208, 34.8537458, 
34.8537736, 34.8537714, 34.8538236, 34.8537781, 34.8538139, 34.8538369, 
34.8537836, 34.8537567, 34.8537628, 34.8538817, 34.8537781, 34.8537881, 
34.8537928, 34.8538686, 34.8537789, 34.85382, 34.85377, 34.8538406, 
34.8536922, 34.8537619, 34.8537433, 34.853785, 34.8536892, 34.85379, 
34.853875, 34.8537903, 34.8537886, 34.8536175, 34.8536267, 34.8538233, 
34.85379, 34.8538144, 34.8537781, 34.8538086, 34.8538706, 34.8537481, 
34.8538278, 34.85389, 34.8536939, 34.8537694, 34.8537817, 34.8538486, 
34.8538756, 34.8536661, 34.8536986, 34.8538383, 34.8537569, 34.8537589, 
34.853695, 34.853625, 34.8537925, 34.8537064, 34.8539625, 34.8537236, 
34.8536778, 34.8538181, 34.8537122, 34.8537711, 34.8538261, 34.8537553, 
34.85381, 34.8537189, 34.8537731, 34.8538992, 34.8537628, 34.8538144, 
34.8543881, 34.8536436, 34.8536719, 34.8535753, 34.8536933, 34.8538072, 
34.8537278, 34.8536269, 34.8537075, 34.8537575, 34.8537406, 34.8537147, 
34.8538469, 34.8537575, 34.85373, 34.8539133, 34.8537914, 34.8537508, 
34.8537761, 34.8537878, 34.8537767, 34.8539447, 34.8537992, 34.8537947, 
NA, 34.8537783, 34.8536497, 34.8538356, 34.8539083, 34.853825, 
34.8537714, 34.8537506, 34.8538225, 34.8537206, 34.8538144, 34.8537892, 
34.853825, 34.8537111, 34.8537472, 34.8537642, 34.8537794, 34.8537856, 
34.85377, 34.8537733, 34.8537356, 34.8536928, 34.8536931, 34.85388, 
34.8536497, 34.8537939, 34.85379, 34.8537389, 34.8536917, 34.8537614, 
34.8536833, 34.8535286, 34.8537486, 34.8537436, 34.8538033, 34.8537428, 
34.8542131, 34.8537464, 34.8536161, 34.8536528, 34.8537589, 34.8537369, 
NA, 34.8538242, NA, 34.8538142, 34.8538356, 34.853775, 34.8537578, 
34.8537811, 34.8538083, 34.8536906, 34.8537503, 34.8538486, 34.8537175, 
34.8538453, 34.8536575, 34.8537547, 34.8537511, 34.8537075, 34.8537744, 
34.8537633, 34.85359, 34.8537122, 34.8538506, 34.8537231, 34.8537228, 
34.8537347, 34.8537283, 34.8538769, 34.8537114, 34.8538169, 34.8537208, 
34.8536908, 34.8538978, 34.8538761, 34.8539753, 34.8539053, 34.8538122, 
34.8538114, 34.8537864, 34.853695, 34.8503172, 34.8304297, 34.814945, 
34.8145011, 34.8138214, 34.8136814, 34.8137883, 34.8139769, 34.8122244, 
34.81164, 34.8114103, 34.8117689, 34.8128397, 34.8128475, 34.8134156, 
34.8135281, 34.8136578, 34.8137497, 34.8139517, 34.8139722, 34.8141908, 
34.8135119, 34.8135247, 34.81347, 34.8136194, 34.81427, 34.8142653, 
34.8142803, 34.81427, 34.81427, 34.8144422, 34.8145519, 34.8145564, 
34.8149731, 34.8150806, 34.8150828, 34.8150828, 34.8159381, 34.8162597, 
34.8163619, 34.8164819, 34.8165492, 34.8167053, 34.8166839, 34.8166936, 
34.8166964, 34.8171572, 34.817145, 34.8171353, 34.8171303, 34.8171256, 
34.8171375, 34.8171381, 34.8171303, 34.8176861, 34.8177839, 34.8178061, 
34.8178208, 34.8177892, 34.8178011, 34.8177817, 34.8177892, 34.8177744, 
34.81777, 34.8177964, 34.8177847, 34.8177714, 34.8177869, 34.8177869, 
34.8177789, 34.8177722, 34.8177914, 34.8177794, 34.8179564, 34.8180086, 
34.8180233, 34.8179689, 34.8179114, 34.8178533, 34.8178789, 34.8178642, 
34.8178664, 34.8178739, 34.8178664, 34.8178664, 34.8178686, 34.8178642, 
34.8178864, 34.8178686, 34.8178619, 34.8178547, 34.8178672, 34.8178775, 
34.8178944, 34.8178642, 34.8178869, 34.8179103, 34.8178444, 34.8178489, 
34.8178733, 34.8178664, 34.8178914, 34.8178761, 34.8178489, 34.8177897, 
34.8177847, 34.8177619, 34.8177964, 34.8178067, 34.8177892, 34.8177828, 
34.8177869, 34.8177744, 34.8177869, 34.8177817, 34.8177794, 34.8177794, 
34.8177869, 34.8177897, 34.8177817, 34.8177811, 34.8178136, 34.8177825, 
34.8177722, 34.8177892, 34.8177864, 34.8177675, 34.8177692, 34.8177825, 
34.8177772, 34.8177994, 34.8177772, 34.8177897, 34.8177308, 34.8177669, 
34.8177517, 34.8177853, 34.8177647, 34.8174078, 34.8170983, 34.8170858, 
34.8170683, 34.8172375, 34.8172303, 34.8172375, 34.817295, 34.8173003, 
34.8173325, 34.8173753, 34.8174275, 34.8175919, 34.8178217, 34.8177339, 
34.8176794, 34.8176844, 34.8177919, 34.8178267, 34.8178614, 34.8178489, 
34.8178267)), row.names = c(NA, -341L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000002531ef0>)
```

Comment: Do you only need to compute distances between two consecutive locations in the list, e.g., the distance from (-2.434901,  34.85359) to (-2.434598,  34.85387)?

Comment: @dipetkov First let me make sure I understand correctly what you mean: the distance from row 1 to 2 is calculated, then the distance from row 2 to 3 is calculated, then the distance from row 3 to 4 etc.. The new distance calculated is summed to the distance calculated previously. Does it make sense?

Comment: @dipetkov If it helps, I could also have an additional column "Date", so each row would represent the total amount of meters travelled in a given date (let's say day by day) with a night/day partition 6h00/18h00

Comment: Yes. I am wondering if this is what you are aiming for. And each pairwise distance can be labeled either Day or Night. Then sum all the Day distances, and all the Night distances. The latter bit can also be done by Date, I guess: Date 1/1/2019 Day distance X, Date 1/1/2019 Night distance Y, etc.

Comment: @dipetkov Yes that would be ideal!

Comment: Use consistent datetime format. Note that "6/18/2018" must be `mdy` (month,day,year) while "18/06/2018" must be `dmy` (day,month,year). You can read more about parsing dates and times in the `lubridate` package documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library("lubridate")
library("geosphere")
library("data.table")

# You probably don't need to create a copy of your own data.
# I did this to avoid an "Invalid .internal.selfref" error from data.table.
dt <- copy(dataraw)

# Preprocess datatimes. Be careful about the format.
# Note that "6/18/2018" must be mdy (month,day,year)
# while "18/06/2018" must be dmy (day,month,year).
# So `dmy_hm` means (day,month,year) followed by (hour,minute).
dt[, DateTime := dmy_hm(`Date & Time [Local]`)]

# Aside:
# The data has NA's in the Latitude/Longitude columns.
# Have you decided how to handle those?

dt[, meters := distGeo(
  cbind(Longitude, Latitude),
  cbind(
    shift(Longitude, 1, type = "lead"),
    shift(Latitude, 1, type = "lead")
  )
)]
dt[, date := date(DateTime)]
dt[, hour := ifelse((hour(DateTime) >= 6) &
                      (hour(DateTime) < 18), "Day", "Night")]
dt[, .(dist = sum(meters, na.rm = TRUE)), .(date, hour)]
#>          date  hour      dist
#> 1: 2018-06-18 Night  880.9310
#> 2: 2018-06-18   Day 8775.9969
#> 3: 2018-06-19 Night  288.1382
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Previous `dplyr` solution.

```r
library("lubridate")
library("geosphere")
library("tidyverse")

df <- tribble(
  ~DateTime, ~Latitude, ~Longitude,
  "6/18/2018 3:01", -2.434901,  34.85359,
  "6/18/2018 3:06", -2.434598,  34.85387,
  "6/18/2018 3:08", -2.434726,  34.85382,
  "6/18/2018 3:12", -2.434816,  34.85371,
  "6/18/2018 3:16", -2.434613,  34.85372,
  "6/18/2018 3:20", -2.434511,  34.85376
) %>%
  # Transform string to date/time
  mutate(DateTime = mdy_hm(DateTime))

df %>%
  # Compute the distance between this row and the next one
  mutate(meters = distGeo(cbind(Longitude, Latitude),
                          cbind(lead(Longitude), lead(Latitude)))) %>%
  # Extract the date and the hour, label hours are Day or Night
  mutate(date = date(DateTime),
         hour = if_else((hour(DateTime) >= 6) &
                        (hour(DateTime) < 18), "Day", "Night")) %>%
  # Sum distances by date and Day/Night
  group_by(date, hour) %>%
  summarise(dist = sum(meters, na.rm = TRUE))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#> # Groups:   date [1]
#>   date       hour   dist
#>   <date>     <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 2018-06-18 Night  111.
```

Comment: I've posted a more extensive answer below mentionning the problem